# Read microphone decibels and pitch/frequency

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, triggers, microphone

I am trying to make a game in which my character shoots when a loud enough sound is heard true the mic (in *Unity*). I have however no idea how to start.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the decibels from a Microphone by retrieving the block of the currently playing Microphone's output data with the [`AudioSource.GetOutputData`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AudioSource.GetOutputData.html) function. To get the dB from this data, you need sum the data samples then calculate the RMS. That's RMS value you can use to calculate the dB with `20 * Mathf.Log10 (RMS / refVal)`.

There is a complete example on about this on [Unity's post](http://answers.unity.com/answers/158800/view.html). You can read that for more information and the code below is based on that:

```
public float rmsVal;
public float dbVal;
public float pitchVal;

private const int QSamples = 1024;
private const float RefValue = 0.1f;
private const float Threshold = 0.02f;

float[] _samples;
private float[] _spectrum;
private float _fSample;

void Start()
{
    _samples = new float[QSamples];
    _spectrum = new float[QSamples];
    _fSample = AudioSettings.outputSampleRate;
}

void Update()
{
    AnalyzeSound();

    Debug.Log("RMS: " + rmsVal.ToString("F2"));
    Debug.Log(dbVal.ToString("F1") + " dB");
    Debug.Log(pitchVal.ToString("F0") + " Hz");
}

void AnalyzeSound()
{
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().GetOutputData(_samples, 0); // fill array with samples
    int i;
    float sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < QSamples; i++)
    {
        sum += _samples[i] * _samples[i]; // sum squared samples
    }
    rmsVal = Mathf.Sqrt(sum / QSamples); // rms = square root of average
    dbVal = 20 * Mathf.Log10(rmsVal / RefValue); // calculate dB
    if (dbVal < -160) dbVal = -160; // clamp it to -160dB min
                                    // get sound spectrum
    GetComponent<AudioSource>().GetSpectrumData(_spectrum, 0, FFTWindow.BlackmanHarris);
    float maxV = 0;
    var maxN = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < QSamples; i++)
    { // find max 
        if (!(_spectrum[i] > maxV) || !(_spectrum[i] > Threshold))
            continue;

        maxV = _spectrum[i];
        maxN = i; // maxN is the index of max
    }
    float freqN = maxN; // pass the index to a float variable
    if (maxN > 0 && maxN < QSamples - 1)
    { // interpolate index using neighbours
        var dL = _spectrum[maxN - 1] / _spectrum[maxN];
        var dR = _spectrum[maxN + 1] / _spectrum[maxN];
        freqN += 0.5f * (dR * dR - dL * dL);
    }
    pitchVal = freqN * (_fSample / 2) / QSamples; // convert index to frequency
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!